# standard or orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Standard basis vectors for R^3 are ( 1 0 0 ) , ( 0 1 0 ) and ( 0 0 1 ) .

//(All Vectors are of order 3-by-1.

If we want to insert vector u into this Basis, then which vector from Standard basis can be removed while still maintaining the Basis of R^3. 
Discuss the cases when:

(i) vector u = ( 4 3 6 )

(ii)     vector u = ( 4 0 6 )
Interpret the result geometrically in both cases.

please help in implementing these questions.
(The order of all the matrices is 3-by-1 )

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

For the first one we need all 3 vectors to represent u=(4 3 6), so it doenst matter which vector of the basis you remove.

For the second one we only need the first and the last vectors of the basis to represent u=(4 0 6), so removing the second basis-vector wont help. We have to remove the first or the last vector of the basis to geht 3 linear independent vectors.